# getElementById in Polymer element

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

How can I use getElementById in a Polymer custom element?

Here is my element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../styles/shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="bb-calendar">

  <template>

    <style is="custom-style" include="shared-styles"></style>

    <div class="card">
            <paper-toolbar>
                <div title>Calendar</div>
            </paper-toolbar>
            <div id="hideme">
                <div>this should be hidden</div>
            </div>
    </div>

  </template>

  <script>

    Polymer({

      is: 'bb-calendar',

      ready: function() {
        document.getElementById("hideme").style.display = 'none';
      }

    });

  </script>

</dom-module>
```

When I run the code I get this error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

Obviously I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd use

```
ready: function() {
  this.$.hideme.style.display = 'none';
}
```

of when the element is inside `<template dom-if...>` or `<template dom-repeat...>`

```
ready: function() {
  this.$$('#hideme').style.display = 'none';
}
```

In the end, I'd use class binding and bind a class to the element and update a property to reflect that change and use CSS to set `style.display`

```
<template>
  <style>
    .hidden { display:none; }    
  </style>
   ...
  <div class$="{{hiddenClass}}">
    <div>this should be hidden</div>
  </div>
```

```
Polymer({

  is: 'bb-calendar',

  properties: {
      hiddenClass: String,
  },

  ready: function() {
    this.hiddenClass = 'hidden';
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Solved the problem with something like what you did in your last answer (non of the others worked for me). 1. fixed the " in the class name. 2. instead of properties I used 'this.hiddenClass'. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and sorry for the mistake. I use only Dart myself.

Comment: I believe the correct syntax in the `ready` handler is `this.$.hideme`, and `this.$$('#hideme')`.

Comment: You are right, I missed `this.`. Thanks foe the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is actually that your element is not attached to the document DOM when the ready callback is fired. For simply showing/hiding an element you may use the hidden attribute like this: `<div hidden$="{{!shouldShow}}">`